# Border and shadow around image not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a border and box shadow around a "main image".
By clicking a "small image" the main image is replaced.

You can see the behaviour [here](http://jsbin.com/welcome/70057/).

Unfortunately I'm not able to set the border and shadow around the main image.

```
 box-shadow:0px 0px 30px black;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px black;
   -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px black;
   border: 4px solid white;
```

Where is the problem and how do I solve it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I´m sure you won´t see a white border on a white background

Comment: Ah well, because of the shadow it looks like a polaroid photo ;-) Btw. it's just a snippet ...

Comment: in this snippet you simply need to aplly your css to ".imgWrap"

Comment: I tried it once, but it just looks crap when I have a smaller image than the first one. That's why I wanted to add the border just right around the image

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any syntax problem. Maybe it's because of the fiddle. The doctype is missing because I just pasted the code I needed. It looks the same with correct syntax ... I really guess that it is a style problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will work fine and does work fine in my browser. I then took at look at link and after search through your source I do not see your CSS being including in the page nor being applied to your image. So I added it.

After doing so I noticed the problem lies with that fact that the `div` in which the main image is including doesn't have the margin/padding for your `30px` dropshadow to show.

Copy and past this in your `CSS` to see it working:

```
.imgOuter {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 775px; //Adjusted Width
    height: 450px; //Adjusted Height
    padding: 20px;
}

.imgOuter img{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #666; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #666;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: 45px; //Added to shift your other images away from new region
}
```

I see you have all your images on the page and have offset styles, using the above `CSS` will require some simple math to adjust your margins back to where you had them.

Working Image:
[image: **Screenshot**]

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint. Stupid me...I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

there are lot´s of syntax errors in your Snippet that cause those problems, for examle opening div tags outside of body and having no doctype opening script tags between head and body etc.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fwelcome%2F70057%23img1&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

I´m sure you will be able to simply apply your css to the img and getting the result by fixing syntax first

Comment: Thanks for your time, but unfortunately I validated the whole template and it doesn't have any syntax errors. The errors you are referring to are from jsbin itself ;-)

Comment: change min-width:100% to a px value and you will see the border around the whole image and not top left only

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `.imgouter` div. It's like a little window where you show things. Your images are the same size as that window, that's why you can't see the boxshadow. (btw you didn't gave them a boxshadow in your jsbin). When you click on the small image you can see the boxshadow if you give this `.imgInner img` a boxshadow. You need to make the `.imgouter` size bigger to see the shadows.

do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/8jM9d/

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
.imgouter {
  border: 4px solid white;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 30px black;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it once, but it just looks crap when I have a smaller image than the first one. That's why I wanted to add the border just right around the image.